# How to get Last Access Time of any file in Android Without Using BasicFileAttribute Class

Tags: java, android, time

I want a `class` which would be a part of an Android application that can directly provide me the last open status or last access status of any file like images, videos. The `BasicFileAttribute.class` seems not to work for me. The solution need to use JDK 8. I don't want to use JDK 7.

Comment: Android doesn't have full support for JDK 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Os.stat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html#stat(java.lang.String)) - since api 21, it returns [StructStat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/StructStat.html) which contains field [st_atime](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/StructStat.html#st_atime) with Time of last access (in seconds). example:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
   try {
      StructStat stat = Os.stat("/path/to/my/file");
      if (stat.st_atime != 0) {
           // stat.st_atime contains last access time, seconds since epoch
      }
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // deal with exception
   }
}
```

Other solution is to execute shell command `stat` :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stat -c \"%X\" /path/to/file");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
  p.getInputStream()));
String line = reader.readLine();
long time_sec = 0;
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty())
 time_sec = Long.parseLong(line);
```

I have not tested above code - but it looks like it should work.

Third aproach would be to use NDK and call `stat` function from C or C++.

Comment: hi Marcin Jędrzejewski ,  thank you so much for the response and the answer , but i have a question that how can i use struct stat can you please share any example which is using this stuctstat and giving last access status if possible like any where implemented in android class or in java class